# ASCII Puzzler 1: Part 1

Tags: lateral-thinking, rebus

*This is a prequel to [ASCII Puzzler 2: Arrows Depicting Movement, Things, or Pointing Out Objects](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32227/ascii-puzzler-2-arrows-depicting-movement-things-or-pointing-out-objects),  [ASCII Puzzler 3: The Trees](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32433/ascii-puzzler-3-the-trees), and https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32439/ascii-puzzler-4-not-a-rebus*

```
o
I ---> {}--{}
I       QQQQQQ <--> QQQQQQ
I       AAAAAA <--> AAAAAA
I       CCCCCC <--> CCCCCC
```

Figure out the sentence using the block of text above.

Hint 1:

> The first thing (read top to bottom, `o I I I I`) is also a cereal brand

Hint 2:

> **Do, obviously, not trace: Base everything you know on this image** *MICROHARDNESS* That is the key to unlocking this clue.

Hint 3:

> Q, A, and C stand for something.

Hint 4:

> Q:  Is it a well known phrase or just some arbitrary sentence?
>  A: Well, it relates. Somehow, this arbitrary clause kills puzzlers' brains. Keep thinking.

Hint 5:

> It is `{}---{}`.

Hint 6:

> You're barely *scratching the surface* of this puzzle... try harder. Maybe your answer will stack up to good answers of hard questions.

Comment: this is puzzling

Comment: Looks like a rebus.

Comment: @Element118, I added the tag. It is a rebus.

Comment: Hmm, wonder if that is a clue… )-:

Comment: I'm terrible with Rebus puzzles, but if it helps someone else, I think maybe hint 1 alludes to "Post", a cereal brand, and the structure of i's looks kind of like a pole/post.

Comment: @Bulldogg6404 I was thinking that was a possibility, but why the lower case i at the top when the others are capitalized?

Comment: @paste I took down the old one, and posted up a new one.

Comment: @Peanut - in this case, if on the picture is all capital I, then shouldn't the hint also be changed?

Comment: I would like to ask, is it a well known phrase or just some arbitrary sentence? I have a hunch about the meanings of each part of the riddle (except microhardness) but cannot come up with a phrase which I've heard of before.

Comment: @hexomino Well, it relates. Somehow, this arbitrary clause kills puzzlers' brains. Keep thinking.

Comment: I googled "microhardness" and the first result was a wikipedia article about indentation hardness. So i guess, indentation is important?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing it's something like

> Post to the Stack Exchange Question/Answer Community

Explanation

> The I's on the left are a post, putting a thing that looks like it could be an empty question and answer onto a **Stack** of things being **exchanged** (the bidirectional arrows). The rest I was just guessing at what Q, A and C could stand for. No idea why there's six of one and half a dozen of the other being exchanged though.

Hint 3:

> Q A and C stand for Question, Answer, and Community, respectively (see the stackexchange.com homepage for those )

Hint 4:

> Taken as examples: Q is the Question and A is the Answer

Hint 5:

> Don't know. Could be related to a stack trace (which unwind sometimes when curly braces are closed) or items being pushed onto a stack. Or it could just be saying that that item is what's being posted.

Hint 6:

> Maybe referring to a scratching post. Also, the word "stack" appears in it.

Comment: Can you provide explanations of Hints 3-6 before I mark it right?

Comment: for Hint 3 : What's usually under the Answers ? maybe ... Comments.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds good. Do you know what the microhardness is about? Is it something to do with indentation as suggested by Pat G?

Comment: @Anton They're under the questions, too, though...

Comment: @hexomino Maybe something to do with having to indent code (the curly braces) in order to format it?

Comment: It seems like the "microhardness" hint is more difficult than the actual puzzle.

Comment: @Peanut, now that *paste* has provided explanations of hints 3-6 are you going to mark this right? Or is it in fact not right?