# ASCII Puzzler 2: Arrows Depicting Movement, Things, or Pointing Out Objects

Tags: rebus

*This is a sequel to [ASCII Puzzler 1: Part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32027/the-ascii-puzzler-part-1) and a prequel to [ASCII Puzzler 3: The Trees](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32433/ascii-puzzler-3-the-trees) and https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32439/ascii-puzzler-4-not-a-rebus.*

Here is the second rebus I have for you to figure out:

```
 |
 V
---        O <---
 B --|--> -|-
---        /\
 ^
 |
```

Here is another rebus I made. The main theme of this is arrows.

Hint 1: (if you reword it, this is a major hint)

> After that the B was flat.

Hint 2:

> A hint to Hint 1: strike out 1, 2, 3, 5.

Comment: Why are there downvotes?

Comment: what are we supposed to do with this?

Comment: "See sharp or be flat"  :)

Comment: @KeyboardWielder nope!

Comment: @KeyboardWielder Drop your piano down the mineshaft to get the answer a tone flat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this is wrong, but the answer could conceivably just be

> B flat minor

on the grounds that

> the person depicted is a miner (perhaps that nice round head is actually a miner's helmet) and he's got a flattened B attached to him. (And, er, "miner" and "minor" sound alike and "B flat minor" is a musical key.)

It seems unsatisfactory because

> there is nothing in the puzzle that actually indicates that the person is a miner (or, I guess, a minor -- i.e., someone not yet legally adult), and all those arrows (featured so prominently in the title) end up not really signifying anything much

so I hope there's a better solution.

Comment: This is one of the most disappointing correct answers I've seen on the PSE... (disappointing to be correct). -1 for question and +1 for answer.

Comment: *For the latecomers who wonders why +500*: This answer is so, so exemplary, that it obviously reserves a +500 (but not from me, from Lukas Rotter's rep bank)

Comment: (The actual reasons are indicated in the open-bounty notice. I think that goes away once the bounty is actually awarded, so here's the story. An anonymous user set up a sockpuppet called "Mushroom Bang Boom", there was some speculation about who it was, and Lukas Rotter offered 500 rep for the first correct guess made in a particular form. Lots of people had the same suspicion but I was the only one who stated it in the requested form. Clearly that was an act of genius richly deserving of a 500-point bounty.)

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that the rebus is referring to

> Acupuncture

via the phrase

> "A sharp stick to the body goes right to the head"

Reasoning

> B flat is equivalent to 'A sharp'. The vertical bar, |, is also called a stick. The arrow from the stick points to the body of the stick figure and the arrow <strike>'going right'</strike> **on the right** points to the head. This may be referring to the apparent placebo effect associated with acupuncture.

Other possibilities

> 'The injection of drugs' or 'voodoo'

Comment: Can you take the "other possibilities" and make them into other answers?

Comment: It's clearly going left to the head :)

Comment: @paste Haha, what a dummy I am! You'd think being able to tell left from right would be a fundamental requirement for trying to solve a visual puzzle.

Comment: @Peanut Hmmm, does that mean I'm on the right track? Essentially, all the possibilities are derived from the phrase in the middle. I'd hate to clog up your question's page with answers only to delete all the wrong ones later on. Although, if you're happy for me to do this...

Comment: @hexomino I was just joking around; I hope I didn't offend (?)

Comment: No, no, not at all. You made a valid point.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

> Be with your crush, and hold hands and kiss??

Because

> B = Be
>  The B is getting crushed, and we also have the hint "*After that the B was flat.*"
>
>  The rest is a bit of a stretch, but the arrows are pointing to the arms (/hand) and head (/mouth). And usually holding hands, kissing (and more ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) ) is what you want to do with your crush.

Comment: Nice try, but that is not the correct answer.