# ASCII Puzzler 3: The Trees

Tags: lateral-thinking, rebus

*This is a sequel to [ASCII Puzzler 1: Part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32027/the-ascii-puzzler-part-1) and [ASCII Puzzler 2: Arrows Depicting Movement, Things, or Pointing Out Objects](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32227/ascii-puzzler-2-arrows-depicting-movement-things-or-pointing-out-objects), and a prequel to https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32439/ascii-puzzler-4-not-a-rebus.*

---

Here is your rebus:

```
 ___   ___   ___   ___   ___
(   ) (   ) (   ) (   ) (   )
(   ) (   ) (   ) (   ) (   )
 | |   | |   | |   | |   | |
 | |   | |   | |   | |   | |
 |_|___|_|___|_|___|_|___|_|___
        |
   -------------
  |1.41421356237|
   -------------
```

Hint 1:

> Sorry if the roots (which are required to be square) are terrible.

Comment: You released a hint *eight minutes* after the puzzle came out?

Comment: @Deusovi It's a comment.

Comment: It's been 8 more minutes. Where's my next hint?

Comment: @Peanut: A comment that you call "Hint 1"

Comment: Not the solution but it may help others to solve the rebus: $\sqrt2 = 1.41421356237...$

Comment: This post is [related](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/32488/21025)

Comment: @Arulkumar this one was made before

Comment: @Peanut : I simply add the reference since both are same kind of logic, that's all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry if I come off as being flippant but is the answer just

> The square root of two?

Because

> As pointed out by fondor in the comments $\sqrt{2} = 1.41421356237\ldots$

and

> This number appears to be attached to the 2nd tree making it a literal 'root' of tree '2'. Also, if the tree's root is required to be square as suggested by the hint then this would be the "square root of 2".

Comment: Thats... surprisingly simple.