# Evaluate the image

Tags: rebus

What does this image evaluate to?

[image: What does this evaluate to?]

Apparently, stack exchange complains if I don't have enough text, so I put this here.

Comment: nice riddle! That was a very clever word play!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you happen to speak a version of English in which "tree" and "three" are near-homonyms (e.g., Irish English) then the answer might be

> $\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt{3}$ or about 3.174. ("Cube root of tree plus square root of tree".)

Answer (score 13):

Does it evaluate to

> 2

as in

> 1 square root + 1 cube root

?

Comment: Nope! You're very close though.

Comment: I figured it was too simple to just put 1 under these operators ;)

Answer (score 6):

> Root of three ("tree") cubed

+

> Root of three squared

=

> $\sqrt{3^3}+3 \approx 8.2$

Comment: I think I like this variation more than the accepted answer! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Incomplete answer. Maybe I'm on the right track?

> The square root is lower than the cube root, which is true for numbers that are less than 1.

So

> It could be any numbers less than 1 so the sum could be anywhere between 0 and 2 (exclusive).